# BluetoothSocket isConnected() function causes java.lang.NoSuchMethodError at runtime

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth

This is the section of code having the problem:

```
    btSocketForCSRComm.connect(); 
    Log.d("MYLOG", "CALLED btSocketForCSRComm.connect()" );

    do{

    }while(btSocketForCSRComm.isConnected()!=true);
    Log.d("MYLOG", "btSocketForCSRComm CONNECTION VERIFIED" );
```

The IDE (Android SDK) does not show any errors (the Logcat works fine upto the first Log.d) but during the while loop it shows an error

```
12-30 12:18:12.661: E/AndroidRuntime(17795): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-30 12:18:12.661: E/AndroidRuntime(17795): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.isConnected
12-30 12:18:12.661: E/AndroidRuntime(17795):    at com.example.bluetoothbasic1.MainActivity$1.onReceive(MainActivity.java:138)
12-30 12:18:12.661: E/AndroidRuntime(17795):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:709)
12-30 12:18:12.661: E/AndroidRuntime(17795):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-30 12:18:12.661: E/AndroidRuntime(17795):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-30 12:18:12.661: E/AndroidRuntime(17795):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-30 12:18:12.661: E/AndroidRuntime(17795):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
12-30 12:18:12.661: E/AndroidRuntime(17795):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-30 12:18:12.661: E/AndroidRuntime(17795):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-30 12:18:12.661: E/AndroidRuntime(17795):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
12-30 12:18:12.661: E/AndroidRuntime(17795):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
12-30 12:18:12.661: E/AndroidRuntime(17795):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Why is this happening? If the isConnect() function does not exist then why didn't the IDE show any errors? Is there any other way to detect if the BluetoothSocket is connected?

Answer (score 2):

The `isConnected()` method was added in Ice Cream Sandwich (SDK 14) as mentioned in [the official API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html#isConnected()). If you use SDK 14 or newer to compile your code but try to run it in an older device then the code will fail with a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` just like it did for you.

There are at least two ways to fix it:

1. Set the minimum SDK version to 14 in the Android manifest (see [uses-sdk](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)).
2. Check the version of Android at runtime and do not call this method unless the device is ICS or newer (see [Build.VERSION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html)).

Comment: The phone is Samsung Galaxy S2 with the default software that came with it (Gingerbread I think it's called). So is it the hardware's problem? Do I have to get a higher specification device?

Comment: I suspect the problem is related to the version of Android, not to the hardware itself.

Comment: Updating software on this phone at the moment is not possible. If I can get a tablet with Jellybean do you think it work?

Comment: It should. You can also try this in Android emulators. Just try an old version first, like 3.2 to replicate the problem, then try JellyBean to make sure that it works on newer versions.

Answer (score -1):

The root cause is that you most likely have compiled a class against a different version of the class that is missing a method, than the one you are using when running it.

If the exception appears when calling a method on objects instantiated by classes you made, then your build process seems to be faulty. Make sure the class files that you are actually running are updated when you compile.

Comment: how do I do that? This is not a class I made, it is from the android library